# Check if value matches mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input that has a mask of date like `__/__/____`. I stored it in a variable. Is there a way to detect if it matches the mask properly?

The event is binded on blur, so sometimes it is returning values like `22/12/___`.

Is there a way to detect if it definitely fits the scheme with integers and slash only or doesn't?

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
   value = $('#my-input').val()   // should be in this format 99/99/9999 and not 12/12/12__

   // here I need to check if it is in right format.
   if (checkFormat(value)) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code too..

Comment: I updated the question and added some code. can you please check

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions - sounds like the right tool for this job.

Comment: Good question, I'll test if the answer works latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to validate this.

```
var regex_check = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ ;
```

**//Edit - Vanilla JavaScript**

```
 function foo(date) {
      var regex_pattern = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ ;
      var check = new RegExp(regex_pattern);
      var res = check.test(date);

      // return true or false
      return res;
    }
```

Comment: can you also add an explanation please

Answer (score 0):

Use `match()` with the following regex : `^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$`

your code will be like :

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    value = $('#my-input').val();
      if (value.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/)) {
        alert("match");
      }
      else {
        alert('the value does not match the regular expression');
      }
}
```